# How to use getProgramAccounts to filter a JS number?

Tags: anchor

I want to get all the program accounts with a filter. The variable `country` is a number in my code and I don't know how to convert it to `bytes` for the filtering to work.

```
const country = 0;

const sellerAccountFilters = {
  filters: [
        {
          dataSize: 198,
        },
        {
          memcmp: {
            offset: 8,
            // How to convert country from number to bytes ?
            bytes: country,
          },
        },
      ],
    };

const sellerAccount = await connection.getProgramAccounts(programID,filters);
```

Thanks in advance,

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `memcmp` bytes are expected to be a base-58 representation of the data to be compared. For numerical data comparisons, you can convert the number of base-58 with:

```
import bs58 from 'bs58'

const country = 0
const sellerAccountFilters = {
  filters: [
    {
      dataSize: 198,
    },
    {
      memcmp: {
        offset: 8,
        bytes: bs58.encode(Buffer.from([country])),
      },
    },
  ],
};
```

With `country` being `0`, this should correctly encode the buffer as `'1'` in base-58.